# Javascript/jQuery Dynamic text to link/href replece

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, href

I need to replace and convert to URL following words on my entire site; Square-Technology UK. I've done some research into replacing text displayed within a site to replace it with url.
Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hgtrh/1/

However it doesn't replace on my website for some reason. Here is the HTML am using.

```
<div class="main_testimonials">
<div class="c_box"></div>
<div class="main_content_img">
<img src="images/news/thumbs/1184901_10151885560986667_1371257993_n_t2.jpg" alt="News" class="news-category"></div>
<div class="main_bubble_box">
Thank you Square-Technology UK for my new system!!
</div>
</div>
```

this is an example of different javascipt that works, note the ' and "

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').removeClass('no-js'); $('#my-carousel-3').carousel({ itemsPerPage: 3, itemsPerTransition: 3, easing: 'swing', noOfRows: 1 }); });</script>\n";
```

Right managed to solve this very easily. My script didn't allow me to use double quotes inside the echo tag in PHP, which is quite obvious. Alternatively using single quotes does not work using the script I posted at the beginning. However the way to do it is just create another file.js, place the code inside it, and then attach it using the following:

```
echo"<script type='text/javascript' src='js/test_replace.js'></script>\n";
```

Comment: You can do this with Javascript, but it does not make too much sense. Do it on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this very easily. My script didn't allow me to use double quotes inside the echo tag in PHP, which is quite obvious. Alternatively using single quotes does not work using the script I posted at the beginning. However the way to do it is just create another file.js, place the code inside it, and then attach it using the following:

```
echo"<script type='text/javascript' src='js/test_replace.js'></script>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var thePage = $("body");
  thePage.html(thePage.html().replace(/Square-Technology UK/ig, '<a href="http://somewebsite.com">Square-Technology UK</a>')); 
})
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Try using a more specific identifier to track what you want to replace instead of tracing the entire DOM to search for what you want to replace:

JS:

```
$(function() {   
  var $siteLink = $('.site-link'),
      linkHtml = '<a href="http://somewebsite.com">Square-Technology UK</a>';

  $siteLink.html(linkHtml);
});
```

HTML:

```
<span class="site-link"></span>
```

However since your fiddle seems to work we can only guess what is happening, can you provide more info about what jquery you are running, or how the page is layout.

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hgtrh/4/

It is also worth mentioning just like ikaros45 said, that this is normally not something you would want to do with Javascript, this seems more like something that the templates should be able to deal with.

Comment: Right, what I think it might be is the way of using, inverted commas, because my attached JavaScripts don't use any double inverted commas inside: echo""; tag. Any way to avoid these?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean at all, Do you mean these kinds of commas as found here ? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/inverted-commas  and are you talking about PHP code?

Comment: Please refer to the additional notes in my post.

Comment: Ah I see what you are doing now, another way to use "double quotes inside a string is like this \" using the \"escape\" character" read more about it here -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

It works on your fiddler example, but not on your site. I suggest confirming that the JQuery library is loading on your site as expected.